# Even thought the array $scope.allAppDetails gets filled the first time. The next time i use the $scope.selectApp function my array is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

angular.module("orgTools").controller("AndroidStatsCtrl", function($scope){

```
    var selectedApp= null;    
    var PerAppDetails= null;
     $scope.allAppDetails= [];
     $scope.perAppStat= PerAppDetails;
     $scope.allAwApps=awAppCategories;
     $scope.processStart=false;
     $scope.allAppsPresent =allApps;$scope.showContent = function($fileContent){

   $scope.allAppDetails.push.apply($scope.allAppDetails, 
                        processFile($fileContent));
        getAllAppCategories($scope.allAppDetails);
       selectedApp= null;
      showLoadGif("loadgifBatteryStat","id","hide");
      $scope.allAWApps=awAppCategories;
      $scope.allAppsPresent=allApps;

};


  $scope.isSelected= function(appSel){

     return  selectedApp===appSel?"btn-primary":"";
  }
```

// inside this function when i use this from the ng-click, the variable  //$scope.allAppDetails becomes empty.

```
  $scope.selectApp = function (newAppSel) {
         selectedApp = newAppSel;
         for(item in $scope.allAppDetails)
            {
              if(allAppDetails[item].name===newAppSel)
                appDetails=allAppDetails[item];

            }

     }
```

Comment: you assign $scope.allAppsPresent =allApps so what is in allApps ?

Comment: Too many unknowns and undefined and undeclared variables. Create a demo that replicates the problem. `$scope.allAppDetails` is not the  same as `allAppDetails` and I suspect you aren't looking at errors in console